# What did Sauron want/manage to achieve from the Seven Dwarven rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

When Sauron gave the Nine Rings to Men, he obtained super-powered Lieutenants (Nazgûl). I'm not sure if there were other side benefits (e.g. Angmar and other realms ruled by Nine allying with him).

What were the benefits - both planned and realized - of giving the Seven Rings to Dwarves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have my copy to hand, so I can't give a direct quote but one specific use that he later had was to try to bribe the dwarves for information by giving them the rings of power he held, and I believe it was generally understood that the rings were the source of great wealth to their bearers.

In particular, this was conveyed by Gloin at the council in Rivendell in book 2, that the messenger of Sauron wanted information about the Shire and Bilbo, and the One Ring, and offered "gifts/rings as he gave of old".

Comment: The dwarven rings are the "gifts of old" in this case, so even if Sauron had offered a captured one to Gloin, Gloin could not have been the original dwarf lord wearing the ring.

Comment: Understood, which is why I said "use that he later had". Also, the ring was (probably) offered to Dain, King under the mountain, rather than Gloin (again, my copy is not to hand, but I think it was with Dain that the messenger of Sauron spoke).

Answer (score 17):

The same thing Sauron wanted with the other Rings:  Complete domination of Middle-earth.

[TolkienGateway.net wiki - Rings of Power](https://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Rings_of_Power)

His original plan is most obvious in the Rings of Men, which slowly corrupted the users until they were fully under his power.  He wanted to do the same with the elves and dwarves.

The dwarves were not dominated, so the rings corrupted them by making them greedy, xenophobic and territorial.  These are traits Sauron could also find useful.

The dwarven rings influence was that the dwarves stayed mostly out of the way of his other plans.  The dwarves also caused endless trouble to the elves during the 3rd age, and that could be a useful side effect of the greed.

Four rings were destroyed by dragons, probably sent by Sauron.  Sauron recaptured the other three dwarven rings, and presumably most of the dwarven treasure with them.

Comment: "complete domination" sounds pretty vague. Are there specific canon examples of what he intended the Rings to do explicitly? Did the rings achieve something canonically tangible that directly aided him?

Comment: Direct cannon evidence about the dwarven rings is limited to the LOTR appendices, the Silmarillion and a few other minor sources.  Canonically, the rings made the dwarf lords obsessed with collecting treasure to the exclusion of everything else, like helping fight Sauron.  I believe Gandalf says something to this effect this in the first book, but I can't find the reference at the moment.

Comment: Indeed, additionally, it is mentioned that the "exclusion of everything else" led to a lack of offspring in the dwarves, where they would not have children, and thus their numbers dwindled, making them weaker with every generation.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I'd love a citation for that...

Comment: @Charles I don't have a LotR citation, but secondary citations.  I did some searching through online copies of the LotR and Silmarillion but could not find a specific reference off-hand, but hopefully these may lead you to them: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_%28Middle-earth%29#Characteristics) - [Wikia.LotR](http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Dwarves#Appearance) - [Tolkien Gateway](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Dwarf-women#Family_and_fertility)

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I don't see that in any of your citations, though. I mean, we know that dwarf women are relatively rare (I don't think there are any canon descriptions of just _how_ rare, but I seem to remember something in the _Letters_), and that they don't reproduce quickly. But I don't know of anything suggesting that obsession with gold, ring-caused or otherwise, has anything to do with that. Unless perhaps you meant something else entirely by "exclusion of everything else"?

Comment: @Charles, There is a mention that only 1/2 or 1/3 of dwarves ever marry and produce offspring, with the remainder pursuing their work.  I took that to be an indication that their work (maybe not necessarily greedy, but at the very least overly industrious) was at odds with the desire to continue the race as a whole.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: I think you're misreading it -- since only a third or a quarter of dwarves are women, some of whom (per Tolkien) never marry, half or a third is the maximum fraction of dwarven men who could possibly marry. It's not that the rest are busy, it's that they're out of luck -- not enough women to go around.

Comment: @Charles That is a good point.  Similar to what is happening in China now (large gender disparity).  While I can't find right off hand the citation for my earlier comment, I still think I recall reading that in canon.  I will keep a look out for it and post if ever I find it again.

Comment: @CodeWarrior: Please do, if you find it! (I'm not sure that China is analogous, though -- they're between 51 and 52% men, compared to 75%+ for dwarves.)

Comment: China may not be a perfect analog, their ratio is quite different, but unfortunately if the disparity gets much worse, I worry that it is going to cause... civil upheaval.  Bad things happen when there are a lot of unmatched Men.